# How to include a pdf as a single page in a tufte-book document?

Tags: tufte

I am using tufte-book.  Is there a way to include a single page from a pdf document into my tuft-book document?

Comment: Try the[`pdfpages`](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/pdfpages/pdfpages.pdf)-package

Comment: Do you want the page to be included as a stand-alone document, or included as an image to fit in with the layout of the rest of your document?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned in the comments, there are two things, first including the page as a standalone page and second as an image fitting the text area.

For including the page as an image, you can use `includegraphics` with the option `page=<page number>` as in

```
\documentclass{tufte-book}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
 \includegraphics[page=50,width=\textwidth,height=\textheight,keepaspectratio]{pgfmanual}
\end{document}
```

On the other hand, if you want to include it as a standalone page, use `pdfpages` package.

```
 \documentclass{tufte-book}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}
 \includepdf[page=50,pagecommand={\thispagestyle{empty}}]{pgfmanual}
\end{document}
```